# Wifi hotspot giving "No internet, secured" on Huawei P10 with Android 8.0.0

Tags: huawei, wifi-hotspot, 8.0-oreo, wifi-tethering, dns

This is driving me bonkers. I've been on a chat with Vodafone and they sent me APN settings, but that hasn't helped. I've tried the settings in [this thread](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/619314-fixed-mobile-tethering-not-working.html).
And that hasn't helped this time (it did a few months ago!!)

If I drop to a CMD prompt, on Windows 10 I can see that DNS is not working.

```
C:\Users\music>nslookup google.com
Server: UnKnown
Address: ::1

*** UnKnown can't find google.com: No response from server
```

which is really odd.

So, I tried to hit the IP address of one of my own web sites, which works.

It's definitely a DNS problem, and I guess the DHCP on the phone is not giving me any DNS server address to use, but how do I force it to do that? I've tried putting static details, and just using `8.8.8.8` and `4.4.4.4` as DNS, but it didn't help at all.

Comment: Is chrome browser what you are only trying to search with or have you tried other browsers? If only chrome maybe clearing/flushing the DNS cache might help. Url Address: chrome://net-internals/#dns

Comment: I've tried within a Windows CMD prompt, and I can ping 8.8.8.8 for example, but if I try to ping google.com I get the error message shown above.

Comment: Also I have tried in ms Edge and I got the same behaviour.

Comment: This might help: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526

Answer (score 0):

This always happens if Vodafone send an update to the APN ... to fix it, just reset your APN settings back to default and select either pre-pay or post-pay, whatever's appropriate for your sim.

Comment: I tried that. Also, tried changing the APN type to various combinations of "default, supl, mms, ia, dun" but NONE of that seemed to help. The weird thing is if I try to ping a known IP address on the internet it works just fine. It's only my DNS that isn't working. Obviously speaking to Voda they weren't much help. I got them to sent me a new settings OTA, but it didn't help. I've got it working using a USB cable, but it will not play ball using Wifi hotspot at all.